# Fix overlapping CSS

Tags: css, mvc-mini-profiler

I started to use [Miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) in my site but encountered rendering issues in its popup. The problem is that my site's CSS are "too global", for example:

```
thead th:last-child {
    background: url("img/rb.gif") no-repeat scroll right 0 transparent !important;
    height: 42px;
}
```

and that conflicts with MiniProfiler's styles and its popup looks like hell (specifically its tables do not need background images, etc.). I tried to narrow down my CSS scopes but the site is huge and that brings more issues (I'm not a designer). However, I can modify MiniProfiler's source code/styles and rebuild it. What I need is that elements in container with `profiler-results` class ignore all "global" styles. What would be my best options?

Comment: show some html code please...

Comment: if this is an issue it should probably be reported as a bug with a repro so we can fix our css up. https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try CSS Scoped, it's an HTML5 features. You can try to find a workaround using this feature since you said that your site so big. And just want to apply a css rule on a particular division on your site.

[Scoped CSS](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/)

Comment: Almost what I need, thanks! Unfortunately it looks like `scoped` attribute can only be specified for embedded styles, not in CSS files or `link` element.